# Can not get Ghostscript to run in chroot on OpenBSD

Tags: php, apache, ghostscript, chroot, openbsd

I have webinstall which wants to use gs (ghostscript) to convert .ps to pdf. But it will not work on openBSD 4.9 because of "chroot" web server ( and I want to stay in "chroot" dirs ) I try to copy all the ghostscript files to the chroot dir /var/www - but it give me error:

```
gs:gs: undefined symbol 'gsapi_new_instance'
lazy binding failed!
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Also it can also only see five libs :

```
# /bin/ldd  /bin/gs
    /bin/gs:
    Start    End      Type Open Ref GrpRef Name
    1c000000 3c004000 exe  1    0   0      /bin/gs
    08611000 28617000 rlib 0    1   0      /usr/lib/libgs.so.11.0
    023af000 223b5000 rlib 0    1   0      /usr/lib/libjpeg.so.64.0
    04d98000 24da1000 rlib 0    1   0      /usr/lib/libpthread.so.13.1
    01c3d000 21c71000 rlib 0    1   0      /usr/lib/libc.so.58.0
    028bc000 028bc000 rtld 0    1   0      /usr/libexec/ld.so
```

when in non chroot :

```
# ldd gs                       
    gs:
    Start    End      Type Open Ref GrpRef Name
    1c000000 3c004000 exe  1    0   0      gs
    0f97d000 2fd19000 rlib 0    1   0      /usr/local/lib/libgs.so.11.0
    0a51c000 2a522000 rlib 0    2   0      /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.so.64.0
    0c537000 2c540000 rlib 0    1   0      /usr/lib/libpthread.so.13.1
    058ae000 258e2000 rlib 0    1   0      /usr/lib/libc.so.58.0
    08dbb000 28dc1000 rlib 0    1   0      /usr/local/lib/libpng.so.10.0
    0bd65000 2bd69000 rlib 0    1   0      /usr/local/lib/libijs.so.0.0
    0dbd9000 2dbe0000 rlib 0    1   0      /usr/lib/libz.so.4.1
    0ff75000 2ff7d000 rlib 0    1   0      /usr/lib/libm.so.5.2
    0a056000 2a135000 rlib 0    1   0      /usr/local/lib/libiconv.so.6.0
    0ce72000 0ce72000 rtld 0    1   0      /usr/libexec/ld.so
```

so I guess "gs" need some libs ? ( gs works fine on cmd line with no chroot.)

Comment: have you copied those libs under /var/www/usr/local/lib ?

Comment: Yes, I have them in /var/www/lib , /var/www/usr/lib and /var/www/usr/local/lib . Just in case but with no luck

Comment: yeah but you have to ldd your libs too and find if they depend on anything. then continue the recursion until you've got them all ;)

Comment: Yes I did and thoese lib are added too...